# I want to check if this formula for IF AND is correct

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I want to check if this formula for IF AND is correct

```
=IF(AND($I2=0,$H2=1,IF($G623<=1849,Sheet3!$AE$7,IF($G623>=1850,Sheet3!$AJ$7))))
```

Basically, if I=0 and H=1, I want it to return the price of this IF($G623<=1849,Sheet3!$AE$7,IF($G623>=1850,Sheet3!$AJ$7)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is actually happening? Did you replace the if with a simple clause?

Comment: So did any of the answers solve your problem? If so don't forget to [pay it forward](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider marking one as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You messed up your conditions/parenthesis.

```
if( CONDITION, TRUE, FALSE )
```

What you wrote is:

```
if( AND( CONDITION1, CONDITION2, CONDITION3 ), ,)
```

What you meant to write:

```
if( AND( CONDITION1, CONDITION2 ), TRUE, FALSE )
```

Where `TRUE` would be your `IF($G623<=1849,Sheet3!$AE$7,IF($G623>=1850,Sheet3!$AJ$7)`.

Answer (score 1):

it isn't, you have to close then AND parenthesis after your last argument as below. this should work.

=IF(AND($I2=0,$H2=1),IF($G623<=1849,Sheet3!$AE$7,Sheet3!$AJ$7))

but it's missing the value that should be return in case I2 is different then 0 or H2 is different than 1 like this (it returns 0)

=IF(AND($I2=0,$H2=1),IF($G623<=1849,Sheet3!$AE$7,Sheet3!$AJ$7),0)

Comment: Consider using a four space indention or a tab to mark your lines as code. That way they'll be formatted differently. Good point about the missing `False` block.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis after the second clause of the AND statement, so it is currently evaluating the nested IF statement as part of the AND. I think what you need is:

```
=IF(AND($I2=0,$H2=1),IF($G623<=1849,Sheet3!$AE$7,IF($G623>=1850,Sheet3!$AJ$7)))
```

Bear in mind that if all of your IF statements here evaluate as FALSE this will just return FALSE rather than a price.